# Enable and disable href link of anchor tag on action of checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, anchor

I want anchor tag to be associated with checkbox.
If the checkbox is not checked the link should remain disabled and if the checkbox is checked then only the link should be enabled for click .

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
  <td>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck{{$index}}" ng-click="initiatedTasksCheck($index)">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{$index}}"></label>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td>
   <h5 class="text-truncate font-size-14 m-0"><a ui-sref="taskdetails ({param1: {{task[2]}}, param2: {{task[1]}} }) " class="text-dark">{{task[0]}}</a></h5>
 </td>
          
</tr>



$scope.initiatedTasksCheck=function(id){
     var checkBoxId="customCheck"+id;
     if($("#"+checkBoxId).is(':checked')){
         /*** How to enable the link ***/
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to add your markup and JS here. What did you try so far?

Comment: I have html . I dont know to link checkbox and <a> in js,